# How to create a box on click in flask?

Tags: javascript, flask

I am new to flask.

How can I make it so that, upon a user clicking an image, a centered box containing a form appears in the div (without a page reload).

Is this possible just using javacript?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please refine your question and include [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this has nothing to do with Flask. As you guess this would be achieved using JavaScript.

As it seems you do not have much knowledge of JavaScript i would suggest you start here : [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Specifically you would need to look into `event handlers`, e.g. [click handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

You can also utilise a third party wrapper library like [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) which will make interacting with DOM elements and events slightly simpler whilst your getting started with JavaScript.

These links will get you started or at least give you the knowledge to come back and ask a more directed question.